# Issue with drop-down menu apperance

Tags: jquery, html, css

For a few weeks I have been working on a Web application project and I am currently working on a drop-down menu. It works quite well except for these 2 points:

- when I roll out the menu by clicking on one of the main items I would like to avoid that the green color rolls out too on the level of the others sub-menu (for instance by clicking on "Menu1" I don't want that a green block appears below "Menu2" and "Menu3")
- I also would like to make my items bigger. But when I activate "padding: 14px 16px;" at the level of #menu li in the CSS code then the sub-menu items are shifted in a bad way.

Could you please help me to solve those issues?
Thanks!

Stéphane

Here is the code:

```js
$(function() {
// Hide sub-menu:
$(".subMenu").hide();
// Hide elements of the screen:
$("#B3 th, #B3 td").hide();
$("[id^='B4_']").hide();
$("[id^='B5_']").hide();
// Hide/Display sub-menu once menu item is clicked:
$( ".mainlink" ).click(function() {
 $(".subMenu").hide(); 
  $("#B3 th, #B3 td").hide();
  $("[id^='B4_']").hide();
  $("[id^='B5_']").hide();
 $(".level1").css("background-color","green");
 $(".level2").css("background-color","orange");  
 $(this).parent().css("background-color","red");
  $(this).parent().find(".subMenu").toggle( "slow", function() {
  // Animation complete.
 });

});

// Hide/Display elements of the body of the screen once sub-menu item is clicked:
// Request/Create
$( "#item1_1" ).click(function() {
$(".subMenu li").css("background-color","orange");
$(this).parent().css("background-color","red");
$("[id^='B5_']").hide();
$("[id='B5_1']").show();
});
// Request/Search
$( "#item1_2" ).click(function() {
$(".subMenu li").css("background-color","orange");
$(this).parent().css("background-color","red");
$("[id^='B5_']").hide();
$("[id='B5_2']").show();
});
// Folder/Report/Create folder
$( "#item2_1" ).click(function() {
$(".subMenu li").css("background-color","orange");
$(this).parent().css("background-color","red");
$("[id^='B5_']").hide();
$("[id='B5_3']").show();
});
// Folder/Report/Create report
$( "#item2_2" ).click(function() {
$(".subMenu li").css("background-color","orange");
$(this).parent().css("background-color","red");
$("[id^='B5_']").hide();
$("[id='B5_4']").show();
});
// Folder/Report/Search
$( "#item2_3" ).click(function() {
$(".subMenu li").css("background-color","orange");
$(this).parent().css("background-color","red");
$("[id^='B5_']").hide();
$("[id='B5_5']").show();
});
});
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #3e8cbd;
}

header {
 border-style: solid;
 margin: 0;
}

footer {
 border-style: solid;
 margin: 0;
}

#menu ul {
 display: flex;
    list-style-type: none; 
    padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
 width: 10em;  
 color: white;
 text-align: center; 
 border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
 border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
 background-color: green;
 /*padding: 14px 16px;*/
}

#menu li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

#menu ul ul {
 flex-direction: column;
 padding: 0;
}

#menu li li {
 background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<!-- Menu items -->
<div id="menu">
 <ul class="menu">
   <li class="level1"><a id="item1" class="mainlink">Menu1</a>
   <!-- Request menu -->
   <ul class="subMenu" id="B2_1">
     <li class="level2"><a id="item1_1" >Sub-Menu1-1</a></li>
     <li class="level2"><a id="item1_2" >Sub-Menu1-2</a></li>
   </ul>
   <!-- Request menu (end) -->
   </li>
   <li class="level1"><a id="item2" class="mainlink">Menu2</a>
   <!-- Dossier/Report screen -->
   <ul class="subMenu" id="B2_2">
     <li class="level2"><a id="item2_1" >Sub-Menu2-1</a></li>
     <li class="level2"><a id="item2_2" >Sub-Menu2-2</a></li>
     <li class="level2"><a id="item2_3" >Sub-Menu2-3</a></li>
   </ul>
   <!-- Dossier/Report menu (end) -->
   </li>
   <li class="level1"><a id="item3" class="mainlink" onClick="alert('Development of the Menu3 functionalities postponed!')">Menu3</a></li>  
 </ul>
</div> 
<!-- Menu items (end) -->

<!-- Screen body -->
<div id="body">
 <!-- B5 block -->
 <table id="B5">
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input id="B5_1" type="button" value="Button1" onClick="alert('Action 1')">
   </td>   
   <td>
    <input id="B5_2" type="button" value="Button2" onClick="alert('Action 2')">
   </td>
   <td>
    <input id="B5_3" type="button" value="Button3" onClick="alert('Action 3')">
   </td>
   <td>
    <input id="B5_4" type="button" value="Button4" onClick="alert('Action 4')">
   </td>
   <td>
    <input id="B5_5" type="button" value="Button5" onClick="alert('Action 5')">
   </td>  
  </tr>
 </table>
 <!-- B5 block (end) --> 
</div>  

</body>
```

Comment: To avoid the "green" below the menu, you should use `position: absolute` in submenus.

Comment: `position: absolute` will make the menu overlap with the buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `position:absolute` or `relative` here will not work because the menu will overlap with the buttons.

I have instead moved most of the `<li>` style to the `<a>`, allowing the `<li>` to grow with the subMenu and the height (and green background) of the `<a>` to be unaffected.

I had a go at simplifying the JavaScript and CSS, moving some style that JavaScript was manipulating back into CSS. I also used the updated the code to use the newer [`.on('click')`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) syntax and used an [HTML data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to link the `<a>` to the button to remove the need to find elements all the time.

```js
// no need to use jQuery to find these all the time
var menuAnchors = $('#menu > li > a'); // cache top level anchors
var buttons = $("input[id^='B5_']"); // cache all buttons

// declare one click handler for all #menu > li > a
$('#menu').on('click', '> li > a', function() {
  menuAnchors.css('background-color', ''); // reset red to green
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; // anchor elements get red background when clicked

  $(".subMenu").hide().reset(); // hide all subMenu
  $(this).next(".subMenu").toggle("slow", function() {}); // show nearest next subMenu
});

// declare one click handler for all .subMenu anchors
$('.subMenu').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).reset();
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; // target anchor set to red
  var buttonId = $(e.target).data('button'); // get buttonId from data attribute
  $('#' + buttonId).show();
});

// custom function to both hide and reset background to orange
$.fn.reset = function() {
  buttons.hide(); // hide all buttons
  $(this).find('a').css('background-color', ''); // reset red to orange
  return $(this);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #3e8cbd;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
  width: 10em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: green;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
}

#menu li:last-child a {
  border-right: none;
}

.subMenu {
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}

#menu .subMenu a {
  background-color: orange;
}

#B5 input {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a class="menuLink">Menu1</a>
    <ul class="subMenu">
      <li><a data-button="B5_1">Sub-Menu1-1</a></li>
      <li><a data-button="B5_2">Sub-Menu1-2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="menuLink">Menu2</a>
    <ul class="subMenu">
      <li><a data-button="B5_3">Sub-Menu2-1</a></li>
      <li><a data-button="B5_4">Sub-Menu2-2</a></li>
      <li><a data-button="B5_5">Sub-Menu2-3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="menuLink" onClick="alert('Development of the Menu3 functionalities postponed!')">Menu3</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<table id="B5">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="B5_1" type="button" value="Button1" onClick="alert('Action 1')">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="B5_2" type="button" value="Button2" onClick="alert('Action 2')">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="B5_3" type="button" value="Button3" onClick="alert('Action 3')">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="B5_4" type="button" value="Button4" onClick="alert('Action 4')">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="B5_5" type="button" value="Button5" onClick="alert('Action 5')">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Position absolute for the submenu, relative for the #menu li
2. No more submenu items shifting because of the point 1.

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ooy3cz4f/)**

```
#main li {padding: 14px 16px; position:relative;}
.subMenu {position:absolute;top:100%;left:0;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi Please update below css and js in your code, it will come whatever you want..

```js
$(function() {
// Hide sub-menu:
$(".subMenu").hide();
// Hide elements of the screen:
$("#B3 th, #B3 td").hide();
$("[id^='B4_']").hide();
$("[id^='B5_']").hide();


// Hide/Display sub-menu once menu item is clicked:
$( ".mainlink" ).click(function() {
 $(".level1").css("background-color","green");
 $(".level2").css("background-color","orange");  
 $(this).parent().css("background-color","red");
  $(this).parent("li").find(".subMenu").slideToggle( "slow", function() {
  // Animation complete.
 });

});

// Hide/Display elements of the body of the screen once sub-menu item is clicked:
// Request/Create
/*
$( "#item1_1" ).click(function() {
$(".subMenu li").css("background-color","orange");
$(this).parent().css("background-color","red");
$("[id^='B5_']").hide();
$("[id='B5_1']").show();
});

// Request/Search
$( "#item1_2" ).click(function() {
$(".subMenu li").css("background-color","orange");
$(this).parent().css("background-color","red");
$("[id^='B5_']").hide();
$("[id='B5_2']").show();
});
// Folder/Report/Create folder
$( "#item2_1" ).click(function() {
$(".subMenu li").css("background-color","orange");
$(this).parent().css("background-color","red");
$("[id^='B5_']").hide();
$("[id='B5_3']").show();
});
// Folder/Report/Create report
$( "#item2_2" ).click(function() {
$(".subMenu li").css("background-color","orange");
$(this).parent().css("background-color","red");
$("[id^='B5_']").hide();
$("[id='B5_4']").show();
});
// Folder/Report/Search
$( "#item2_3" ).click(function() {
$(".subMenu li").css("background-color","orange");
$(this).parent().css("background-color","red");
$("[id^='B5_']").hide();
$("[id='B5_5']").show();
});
*/
});
```

```css
header {
 border-style: solid;
 margin: 0;
}

footer {
 border-style: solid;
 margin: 0;
}

#menu ul {
 display: block;
    list-style-type: none; 
    padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
 width: 10em;  
 color: white;
 display: inline-block;
 float:left;
 width: 150px;
 height: 35px;
 line-height: 35px; 
 text-align: center; 
 border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
 border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
 background-color: green;
 /*padding: 14px 16px;*/
}

#menu li ul li{
 padding: 7px 32px;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;

}
#menu li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

#menu ul ul {
 flex-direction: column;
 padding: 0;
}

#menu li li {
 background-color: orange;
}
```